# Is google app engine backend feature gonna be deprecated?

Tags: google-app-engine

The https://developers.google.com/appengine/ indicates that backends is deprecated. What is the alternative to backends?

Answer (score 2):

Modules

> App Engine Modules (or just "Modules" hereafter) is a feature that
>   lets developers factor large applications into logical components that
>   can share stateful services and communicate in a secure fashion.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/